# How to make a progress dialog compatible with higher version of android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using a progress dialog in my app to load app contents. It was working good but when i am using this app in android lollipop or marshmallow, it is showing me a white dialog box with my progress dialog.

Comment: can you show screenshots of both (working and non-working) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use material design progress bar it will work fine with both higher and lower version of android. 
Refer below link for more information 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 1):

For material theme on all android versions, you have to use `AppCompatActivity`.

For Example,

In Activity say **A**

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ...
}
```

And in **Manifest.xml**,

```
<application
       ...
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeActionBar"
       ...
>
</application>
```

And in **style.xml**,

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Make sure you add dependency in gradle,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use support library widgets to make it look consistent across various android versions. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Can you explain me, which support library i should use?

Comment: Progress dialog works only in the way you mentioned because of the inherited styles for various versions of android. But components/widgets like  Switch, Toolbar etc u can use the support library versions like android.support.v7.widget.switchcompat and android.support.v7.widget.toolbar :)